# Find out constants$~a,b,c,d~$such that$~\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^{}\left(3x\right)-\left(ax^{2}+bx+c\right)}{x^{3}}=d~$is satisfied

Tags: limits, asymptotics, constraints, constants, conditional-convergence

$$\left(a,b,c,d:=\text{constants}\right)~~\wedge~~\left(d\neq0\right)$$

I want to find out the formula(s)or value(s)of the above constants which satisfy the following equation.

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^{}\left(3x\right)-\left(ax^{2}+bx+c\right)}{x^{3}}=d\tag{1}$$

$$\sin^{}\left(3x\right)^{\left(n\right)}=3^{n}\sin^{}\left(x+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$

And by using taylor expansion expression, the following is said.

$$\sin^{}\left(3x\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{}\left(3x\right)^{\left(i\right)}|_{x=0}x^{i}}{i!}$$

$$\sin^{}\left(3x\right)^{\left(i\right)}|_{x=0}=3^{i}\sin^{}\left(\frac{i\pi}{2}\right)$$

$$\sin\left(3x\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{i}}{i!}\cdot 3^{i}\sin\left(\frac{i\pi}{2}\right)$$

I think I made no mistake so far, however I can't get how$~o(x^{3})~$has been appeared.

$$\sin\left(3x\right)=3x-\frac{9}{2}x^{3}+\underbrace{\sum_{i=4}^{\infty}\frac{x^{i}}{i!}\cdot 3^{i}\sin\left(\frac{i\pi}{2}\right)}_{\text{min degree is}~5}$$

$$=3x-\frac{9}{2}x^{3}+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{5}\right)~~\leftarrow~~\text{Newest my progress so far}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^{}\left(3x\right)-\left(ax^{2}+bx+c\right)}{x^{3}}=d\tag{1}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x-\frac{9}{2}x^{3}+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{5}\right)-ax^{2}-bx-c}{x^{3}}~~\leftarrow~~\text{What can I do for next?}$$

Comment: Don not separate into two fractions. Use Taylor approximation for the sine function with an error term $\mathcal{O}(x^5)$.

Comment: I need firstly study Landau notation of sin(x)..

Comment: Intuitively, you need to use $a,b,c$ to cancel out the constant, $x$, and $x^2$ terms of $\sin(3x)$.  Then the $x^3$ term will dominate and cancel the denominator.  The ratio is $d$.  As Gary says, the Taylor approximation gets you there.

Comment: Since in $\sin (3x)$ there are neither constant term nor term with $x^2$ it follows that $a=c=0$.  Then with $b=3$ you cancel $x$. The term including $x^3$ has coefficient $\frac{3^3}{3!}=\frac{9}{2}$. So, with $a=c=0, b=3$ you get $d=\frac{9}{2}$.  You can prove this fact by l'Hospital rule.

Comment: @kmitov I think I can make more progress after I got your this commentary.

Answer (score 2):

We can use Taylor - McLaurin expansion, for $\sin(3x)$:
$$\sin(3x)=3x-\frac{9}{2}x^3+o(x^3)$$
The limit becomes:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(3x\right)-\left(ax^{2}+bx+c\right)}{x^{3}}=d\implies 
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3x-\frac{9}{2}x^3+o(x^3)-\left(ax^{2}+bx+c\right)}{x^{3}}=d$$
Note that if, for example, $b\neq 3 \land a=c=0$, you are going to have $+\infty$. Can you justify the other cases?

Consequently, the only case acceptable is:
$$b=3  \,\,\land \,\, a=c=0\implies \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{9}{2}x^3+o(x^3)}{x^3}=\frac{9}{2}$$

Comment: @electrical apprentice: if this answer has been useful, lety me know, smashing the +1 button and accepted answer. Thanks.